# how to upload a file to database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

ok so im trying to upload to a database, the name of file selcted, the type, the size(in bytes) and the file it self to the db. so far i got everything going except uploading the file it self to the db.  so my qustion is how would i upload the file itself to the db

here is my code i already have

```
    Dim s = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    MessageBox.Show("File Name:" & s.Name)
    MessageBox.Show("File Type:" & s.Extension)
    MessageBox.Show("File Size (Bytes):" & s.Length)
    Try

        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
        Dim insertStatment As String = "INSERT INTO upload (name, type, size) VALUES 
        (@name, @type, @size)"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(insertStatment, db_con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", s.Name)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", s.Extension)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@size", s.Length)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("ok")
        db_con.Close()
           Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong, please try again")
        db_con.Close()
       End Try
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's not necessary to put information in the title of your question that you can put in tags. The tag system works very well here. Thanks. :-) (Nicely asked question, by the way. +1.)

Comment: Are you sure you want to upload the file itself to the db? The are some reason behind that (especially if the db is used by some system out of your control, and you just have to conform to it, etc.), but have you considered storing the file separately somewhere in the file system and storing only the path in the db?

Comment: Please see my post ,it work for me
[Insert a file to MySQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47276606/insert-a-file-to-mysql-database/47276721?noredirect=1#comment81504744_47276721)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link

http://mirificampress.com/permalink/saving_a_file_into_mysql

This is what I used when I was having the same issue just a month ago and it worked for me. It's in C# however it's exactly the same for VB.NET and I trust it wouldn't be an issue for you to translate the C# code given here into VB.NET

Comment: that is not in C#, that's PHP.

Comment: oh and the link is in php not c#