# Insert a File to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I searched on how to insert an image here that helps me,now I need to insert a file to my database,please help me I have a data type of LONGBLOB for column name (binary) and nvarchar(50) for column name (file),but cannot insert a file and gives me an error that says I have an error in sql syntax.Any help will much appreciated.Thanks

This is my code for upload

```
 '          Extract File name
        Dim FullFileName() As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.Split("\")
        Dim fname As String = FullFileName.Last.ToString()
        Try
            '  read data file
            Dim fileContent() As Byte

            Dim FSteream As New FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open)
            Dim BReader As New BinaryReader(FSteream)

            fileContent = BReader.ReadBytes(FSteream.Length)
            FSteream.Close()
            BReader.Close()

            '  insert file to db
            conn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into file_tbl(file,binary) values (@name,@data)"
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", fname)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", fileContent)

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            '    '----
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message + " inside upload button")
        Finally
            MsgBox("File : " & fname & " Uploaded .")
            conn.Close()
            cmd.Dispose()
        End Try
```

Comment: `Binary` is a reserved word in MySQL.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Thanks Sir!,I successfully uploaded my file,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of converting to file into byte, save file to common folder and save link to the file in database table field.

Comment: That's a great idea,does the link affected if the common folder transferred to another address?I'm afraid only if he common folder deleted accidentaly.

Comment: if the folder not exist then certainly link will be broken. But putting folder in system files, there will be lack of chances to getting delete it. And also for better practice systems should taken backups by administrators in system maintenance part